# How to add the KML layer for Openlayers switcher?

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, openlayers, kml

how can i add a KML layer to the switcher by [ol-ext Viglino](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext/blob/master/examples/control/map.switcher2.html)?

When I add:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
  url: "IG1.kml",
  format: new ol.format.KML()
})
```

The layer does not appear on the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To appear in the layer switcher the layer must have a title property

```
var vectorSource = new ol.layer.Vector({
  title: "KML Layer",
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: "IG1.kml",
    format: new ol.format.KML()
  })
})
```

If the layer is not appearing on the map check that `.kml` extension is enabled in your server MIME types.

Comment: "title" is not necessary, but I added. Still doesn't work. Where to check if the extension is enabled? KML file is working on the https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-and-drop-custom-kmz.html

Comment: Can you open the kml via a webbrowser?  e.g. `http://myserver.com/path/IG1.kml`

Comment: The KML I have on the https://geologie.tk/IG1.kml, when i open this URL the KML is downloaded.

Comment: The downloaded file is zipped.  You could treat it as a KMZ using a custom format as in the example, or rename the downloaded file as .zip, extract the doc.kml file and copy that to your server.

Comment: Copying to your own server is the best option as the link is not CORS enabled.

Comment: Thank you very much, Its working on the server, on the localhost not.

Comment: Localhost uses IIS so you probably need to open the console and add kml to the mine types https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PFlk.png

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
import KML from 'ol/format/KML';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import {Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer';

const vector = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource({
    url: 'IG1.kml',
    format: new KML(),
  }),
});
```

Comment: I found this example (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/kml.html), but its not working with Switcher by  ol-ext Viglino.